# Jquery Attr is not working without buttons tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

atrr function not giving a desired response, I have a small code that fetches data from external API that has couples of data in dict.

```
<div id="facet-knowledge-panel" style="margin-left: 70px;">
        <h2 id="facet_panels_title"></h2>
        <div id="facet_panels_content"></div>
    </div>

    <button id="open">open</button>
 
    <script>
        let facet_kp = "http://localhost/render-to-html?facet_tag=category&value_tag=en:beers";

        fetch(facet_kp)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.text();
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error("Network Response Error while fetching facet kp");

                }
            })
            .then(data => {
                let title = document.getElementById("facet_panels_title");
                title.innerHTML = "Facet knowledge panel";

                let knowledgepanel = document.getElementById("facet_panels_content");
                knowledgepanel.innerHTML = data;
            })
    </script>
```

Here, id="facet_panels-content" will return data after fetching from API it contain data in "<details><summery>......" tag but I want to keep the details tag open by default.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#open").click(function(){
            $("#HungerGames").attr("open",true);
          });
        });
</script>
```

I'm using thing Jquery code to open single details tag using a button and it working fine but I want to make it open by default without any button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#HungerGames").attr("open",true);
        });
```

So, If I use this it does not open the "details" tag of this id. I want to keep "details" tag open by default without any buttons.

Comment: Can you provide us the HTML included in `data`?

Comment: And you say it "does not open", but do `$("#HungerGames")` have an `open` attribute after that? If yes, it works and the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `#HungerGames` selector doesn't match any element in your HTML.

So presumably this operation is adding it to the page?:

```
knowledgepanel.innerHTML = data;
```

Then clearly you can't interact with that element until *after* it's been added to the page.  So instead of trying to show the element when the page loads, show it when it's added to the page:

```
knowledgepanel.innerHTML = data;
$("#HungerGames").attr("open",true);
```

Comment: That is not working! And yes, "knowledgepanel.innerHTML = data;" is injecting the data in the page.

Comment: @SumitKashyap: What specifically is "not working"?  When you debug, does `$("#HungerGames")` find the element you're looking for?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  Because this [demonstrably works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/v3y46fko/).

Comment: Yes, `$("#HungerGames")` cannot find the element , regrading minimal reproducible example here you can change `facet_kp` with this https://facets-kp.openfoodfacts.net/render-to-html?facet_tag=category&value_tag=en:beers

Comment: @SumitKashyap: If the element can't be found then it isn't in the markup.  You are encouraged to provide a runnable [mcve] which *demonstrates* the problem.  Currently the only obvious problem in the question is that you're trying to interact with an element before it exists, and the solution is to interact with that element after it exists.  There may be *some other problem* in your code as well, unrelated to this one.  But we can't know if you can't demonstrate it.

Comment: it solved now it was problem in my code(small typo) sorry for the trouble :-)